# Trying to create basic application using HERE Android Lite SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to run a basic example of an application with new Android Lite SDK from HERE and getting such error:

```
E/AndroidTangramPlatformBridge: parse
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: END_TAG expected (position:START_TAG (empty) <axis tag='wdth' stylevalue='100.0'>@279:51 in java.io.InputStreamReader@739274e) 
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:2088)
        at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.FontFileParser.processDocument(Unknown Source:105)
        at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.FontFileParser.parse(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.FontFileParser.parse(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.AndroidTangramPlatformBridge.<init>(Unknown Source:33)
        at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.here.hellomap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl: isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{d1ae1ac token=android.os.BinderProxy@853d260 {com.here.hellomap/com.here.hellomap.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@853d260
E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: set config for com.here.hellomap BOOST_FLAG=false REPORT_DURATION_CLICK=1000 REPORT_TIMES_CLICK=3 REPORT_DURATION_SLIDE=5000 REPORT_TIMES_SLIDE=16
D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
W/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: depended package hiTouch does n't exist!
I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: HiTouch restricted: system app HiTouch don't exist.
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=com.here.hellomap, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=true
E/analytics: [ERROR] analytics - Failed to get the authentication token: Authentication failed, error code: 1
E/analytics: [ERROR] analytics - Failed to get the authentication token: Authentication failed, error code: 1
    [ERROR] analytics - Invalid access key
I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
```

I see only a blank map on my HUAWEI P Smart (on Virtual device code runs normally).
Does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: It seems like the XML file you are trying to parse is not valid. It is missing an end tag somewhere in the config.

Comment: Does it run any of the examples coming with the SDK package ?

Comment: I also think the XML is just a warning and not the error. The lines at the end of the log concern me more: "E/analytics: [ERROR] analytics - Failed to get the authentication token: Authentication failed, error code: 1
    [ERROR] analytics - Invalid access key" - Can you please double check the credentials. Please make sure (if you copy&paste) that there's no space or linebreak at the end of the id/secret ?

Comment: I tested again on the virtual device and everything works. I saw only warning of AndroidTangamBridge but it didn't influence the appearance. Also, I didn't get any errors connected with Credentials. To be sure I took an example from the official GitHub - https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/android/HelloMap. 
Now I tried to run an app on Galaxy Tab A and it started to work! So it is a problem with the device I guess...

Comment: One more idea about that particular device: Since authentication and tokens are based on correct date/time setup on the phone, you might want to check if date/time setup on the phone is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please check authentication token for android Lite version. Also check for the permission java class that has to be correctly written. The accompanying example apps can be found on GitHub : https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples

To try out these examples, add your HERE credentials (access_key_id and access_key_secret) to the AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the HERE SDK to the libs folder.